# Webpack file-loader using function in outputPath gives EISDIR illegal operation on a directory

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm trying to generate a certain output for my locale files that is like **_locales/[locale_shortcut]/[file].json**

For this I'm using the file-loader plugin in webpack. According to the documentation, it's possible to use a function inside the option outputPath. There's however no documentation on how it should look like, and/or what the function should return. My best guess was that it returns a string just like the string value you would use directly in outputPath...

Using the following code for files that are named like **[locale_shortcut].locale.json**:

```
{
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
        name: "[name].[ext]",
        outputPath: (t: any) => {
            return "_locales/" + t.replace(".locale.json") + "/";
        },
    },
},
```

I get the error:

> EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/[user]/projects/[project]/dist/_locales/en/'

Used dependencies:

- file-loader 2.0.0
- webpack 4.27.1
- typescript 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Apparently I have to add the filename at the end of the return path for it to work :/